# capitalize the first letter of two words separated by underscore using stringr

Tags: r, stringr

I have a string like `word_string`. What I want is `Word_String`.  If I use the function `str_to_title` from `stringr`, what I get is `Word_string`. It does not capitalize the second word.

Does anyone know any elegant way to achieve that with `stringr`? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a base R option using `sub`:

```
input <- "word_string"
output <- gsub("(?<=^|_)([a-z])", "\\U\\1", input, perl=TRUE)
output

[1] "Word_String"
```

The regex pattern used matches *and* captures any lowercase letter `[a-z]` which is preceded by either the start of the string (i.e. it's the first letter) or an underscore.  Then, we replace with the uppercase version of that single letter.  Note that the `\U` modifier to change to uppercase is a Perl extension, so we must use `sub` in Perl mode.

Answer (score 3):

Can also use `to_any_case` from `snakecase`

```
library(snakecase)
to_any_case(str1, "title", sep_out = "_")
#[1] "Word_String"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "word_string"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously overly complicating but another `base` possibility:

```
 test <- "word_string"
paste0(unlist(lapply(strsplit(test, "_"),function(x) 
  paste0(toupper(substring(x,1,1)),
           substring(x,2,nchar(x))))),collapse="_")
[1] "Word_String"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first use `gsub` to replace `"_"` by `" "` and apply the `str_to_title` function

Then use `gsub` again to change it back to your format

```
x <- str_to_title(gsub("_"," ","word_string"))
gsub(" ","_",x)
```