# Rename all columns to title case with {dplyr}

Tags: r, dplyr

I would wish to rename all the columns so that `first_name` becomes `First_Name` and `last_name` becomes `Last_Name`. Using `str_to_title()` will captalize the first letter... Any ideas

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~'first_name', ~'last_name', ~'age',
  "John", "Kambusa", 45,
  "Jane", "kumbuka", 40,
)

df |> 
  rename_with(~str_to_title(.x))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257172/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-two-words-separated-by-underscore-using-stringr

Comment: Following @benson23's link suggestion, `colnames(df) = sub("(?<=^|_)([a-z])", "\\U\\1", colnames(df), perl = TRUE)` is all you need to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to capitalize...

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- tribble(
  ~'first_name', ~'last_name', ~'age',
  "John", "Kambusa", 45,
  "Jane", "Kumbuka", 40
)

# Custom function to capitalize the first letter of each word
capitalize_words <- function(x) {
  str_to_title(gsub("_", " ", x))
  
  #str_replace_all(str_to_title(x), " ", "_")
}

df <- df %>%
  rename_all(~capitalize_words(.x)) %>% 
  rename_all(~str_replace_all(.x, " ", "_"))

print(df)
```

Output

```
 First_Name Last_Name   Age
  <chr>      <chr>     <dbl>
1 John       Kambusa      45
2 Jane       Kumbuka      40
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a regex solution in a single line, using (i) capture groups to target the letters to be converted to upper-case - the first being the string-first letter (`^`), the second being the first letter after the underscore - and backreference `\\1` preceded by `\\U` (for upper-case):

```
df |> 
  rename_with(~ gsub("(?<=^|_)(.)", "\\U\\1", .x, perl = TRUE))
```

**EDIT**:
or, with far less regex but function `str_to_upper` instead (credit to Adriano Mello):

```
df %>%
  rename_with(~ str_replace_all(., "(^|_).", str_to_upper))
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the @Chris' solution, here's the `stringr` version. "Replace all lowercases preceded by word boundary or punctuation with uppercases":

```
rename_with(df, \(x) str_replace_all(x, "(\\b|[:punct:])[:lower:]", str_to_upper))
```

Comment: Nice, but consider phrasing it more concisely: `rename_with(df, \(x) str_replace_all(x, "(\\b|_).", str_to_upper))`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @ChrisRuehlemann! I tend to use more explicit/descriptive patterns or commands to make my little contributions as acessible as possible to others amateurs like me. Regex can be quite difficult to read sometimes.

Answer (score -2):

Using dplyr colnames can be changed to title case. Note sub is used to change to title case words after "_".

`names(df)<-sub(" ","_",str_to_title(sub("_"," ",names(df))))`

Using dplyr we can convert the values also to title case

`df  %>%  mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_to_title(.x)))`

Comment: This isn´t an answer. It mutates values, not colnames. Even if applied to colnames, it doesn´t produce the expected output.

Comment: This works on the values of a column not the column itself

Comment: My bad. Have rectified the error.